# Write a prolog rule to compute each city’s altitude in meters

Tags: prolog

Write a Prolog rule to compute each city’s altitude in meters. Note that an altitude in meters can be computed as 0.3048 * altitude in feet.

i.e., define the new predicate:city_altitude_in_meters(City, State, Feet, Meters):-

I’ve already tried the following:

```
f_to_m(F_altitude,M_altitude):-
   M_altitude is (F_altitude)*0.3048.

city_altitude_in_meters(city, state,F_altitude, M_altitude):-
   (M_altitude is(F_altitude)*0.3048).

city_altitude(tempe, az, 1318).
city_altitude(atlanta, ga, 894).
city_altitude(chicago, il, 583).
city_altitude(denver, co, 5280).
city_altitude(seattle, wa, 260).
city_altitude(boise, id, 2704).
city_altitude(saltlakecity, ut, 4226).
```

I expect the output of (tempe, az, 1318, 401.726).

Comment: Two comments/hints. 1) Variables must start with Upper case letter (or `_` but that's not relevant here). 2) In `city_altitude_in_meters`, you must add some connection with a city, its state and its altitude.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog predicates are best when they work forwards and backwards, so let's start with your `f_to_m/2` predicate and remove any notion of direction from it:

```
feet_meters(Feet, Meters) :-
    nonvar(Feet), !,  % Cut so second rule isn't used if nonvar(Feet)
    Meters is Feet*0.3048.
feet_meters(Feet, Meters) :-
    nonvar(Meters),
    Feet is round(Meters/0.3048). % rounded because computers and floating point arithmetic headaches, plus all your altitudes in feet are integers.
```

Now you can convert between feet and meters in both directions. We're checking what inputs are variables to ensure we use the correct rule, we'll fail if both inputs are variables.

Then you just need to apply this conversion predicate to the cities:

```
city_altitude_in_meters(City, State, Feet, Meters):-
    city_altitude(City, State, Feet), % for when City or State are variables
    feet_meters(Feet, Meters).
```

In this way you can even query:

```
?- city_altitude_in_meters(City, State, Feet, 79.248).
```

It's always a good idea when writing Prolog to think about running it in both directions and with all combinations of variables, including the worst-case query which would be the example above.

Comment: Why not replace the cut with explicit `var(Meters), nonvar(Feet)` guards? What about the `var(Feet), var(Meters)` case? Currently `?- feet_meters(X,Y).` does not have solutions - an instantiation error would be more helpful. Obviously the nonvar / nonvar case needs to be handled as well then.

Comment: The `nonvar` guards are the minimum required to prevent each rule from throwing an error, either can handle the case where both arguments are `nonvar`. The cut prevents leaving an unnecessary choice point during expected use, but the guards ensure unexpected use does not fail. The case where both are `vars` has no rational solutions as we're in infinite ranges, in this case it simply fails but throwing an error would be wise. I used a cut to mimic the `(_ -> _ ; _ )` syntax without needing to explain it.